# Strange Greater than or Less than Results

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing a strange problem, really not sure why :(

So have a look at the below (all cells formated as percentage with 2 d.p.):

[Sheet http://im61.gulfup.com/xXpJZu.png](http://im61.gulfup.com/xXpJZu.png)

Now here is Code1:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value < Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value Then
MsgBox "Yes"
Else
MsgBox "Nope"
End If
```

**Result:** Working correctly and displaying "Nope" since the word "Text" cannot be less than a number/percentage.

Code2:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value > Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value Then
MsgBox "Yes"
Else
MsgBox "Nope"
End If
```

**Result:** Not working correctly and displaying "Yes". And this is the problem. I don't understand why it considers the word "Text" as greater than "10%" or "0.1".

I thought for a second that the problem might be in the formatting of the cells, so I changed it to General & then to Text but I am still getting the same results.

Also, what surprises me most is that when I am putting in the "<" sign it works correctly, but gives wrong results when using the ">" sign.

What am I missing?

Comment: Image is not showing for me.

Comment: Hmmm. Your two formulas are identical except for the comparison operator.  Why would you expect to see the same result?  In any event, with VBA's comparison operators, if one expression is a number and the other a string, the number will be less than the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First it is important to note that the type of `Range(...).Value` is `Variant`, which you can confirm by using the watch window.

The answer is then found at the bottom of the msdn VBA language reference page for [Relational Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200271.aspx):

> •There is an exception to the rules in the preceding table when both
>   operands have a declared type of Variant, with one operand originally
>   having a value type of String, and the other operand originally having
>   a numeric value type. In this case, the numeric operand is considered
>   to be less than (and not equal to) the String operand, regardless of
>   their values.

Comment: It's also in VBA HELP under comparison operators "One Variant expression is **numeric** and the other is a **string**: The numeric expression is **less than** the string expression."

Comment: I see. Did not know that! Probably should have read deeper into the reference pages :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison coalesces to a text comparison when a string and number are compared, in order to get the result you want you must include a test with ISNUMBER() like this, where the formuls is displayed in row 1 :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In vba this is `If IsNumeric()`. Using this I have nested an If function to first checked that the value is not numeric, only if so then check if it is greater than or less than. But I had this all along, I just wanted to understand what was the logic behind the different results when using "<" as opposed to ">".